# Python nested loops that do not act as I would expect them to

Tags: python, arrays

This is NOT a homework problem. Code very similar to this is the basis for a larger project. It has been a while since I used python regularly.

```
width = 10
height = 10
board = [[0]*(2*width + 1)]*(2*height + 1)
for k in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        if (k%2 == 1):
            board[k][j] = 11
result = []
for i in board:
    for j in i:
        result.append(str(j))
        result.append(" ")
    result.append('\n')

print("".join(result))
```

This is the output, copied and pasted directly just as the code:

```
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I intended the code to do is that the first nested loop should populate the 21 by 21 array with 11 for every element in the 10 by 10 top left hand corner of the array. Then the second nested loop should output that array. What am I doing wrong? Thank you, I am so confused because I feel I have solved this problem a million times before yet it is not turning out as expected

Comment: You board contains the same list over and over. You need a fresh list for each row eg. `board = [[0]*(2*width + 1) for x in range(2*height + 1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic problem: `[[0]*(2*width + 1)]*(2*height + 1)]` creates a single "row" `[0]*(2*width + 1)` and then a list of `(2*height + 1)` references to that single row.

To create multiple copies, you can use this instead:

```
[[0]*(2*width + 1)] for _ in range(2*height + 1)]
```